# How to except a variable to be of a specific type with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How could I use Jest to ensure that a variable is of a specific type, like a `string` or a `number`?

There is no such thing as

```
expect(myVar).toBeString()
expect(myVar).toBeNumber()
```

am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
expect(myVar instanceof Type).toBe(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how crazy you want to get with it in determining type with js, you can just use `typeof` to equal the string value of the type.

```
expect(typeof myVar).toBe('string')
expect(typeof myVar).toBe('number')
```

Otherwise, just test against the condition to be true, or truthy.

```
expect(Array.isArray(['value'])).toBe(true);
```